# WCF ServiceHost REST API goes idle after some time, returns timeout error

Tags: rest, wcf, service

We are facing a production-issue with WCF REST API hosted in a Windows Service.

We have clients making GET and PUT requests and also regular Ping() requests to the service from clients every 30 sec.

All the Get,Put requests work well for some time (2 or 3 days) and later at some point no WEB-API requests are served. We had to restart the Windows service again to bring back the REST-service into working state.

Client Error msg: Status Code is 503 service unavailable.

Able to reproduce the issue in local Dev-environment by below scenario.

Simulated continuous REST calls to service in local with the help of sample test client upon making Ping request every 2 seconds and Put request every 4 Seconds continuously we are able to reproduce the issue within 5 Minutest after making 68 Put requests and 152 Get requests . There was no errors logged in service. Status Code is 503 service unavailable.

Here is the server configuration for WCF REST service.

### WCF REST Service Configuration:

```
var restURL = string.Format("{0}{1}/v{2}", (isHttps ? WsSprotocol : WsProtocol), Config.Server, Config.Version);
            var webServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(EngageWebServiceHostREST), new Uri(restURL));
```

`var webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding
        {
            Security = new WebHttpSecurity { Mode = isHttps ? WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport : WebHttpSecurityMode.None },
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            ReaderQuotas = { MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue },
            OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 01, 00),
            CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 00),
            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 00),
            CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true,
            TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse
        };

        if (isHttps)
        {
            bindHttpCertificate(webServiceHost);

            if (webServiceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate != null && webServiceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate != null)
            {
                webHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
                Log.Info(string.Format("Https Certificate {0} binded to {1}", webServiceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate.SubjectName.Name, restURL));
            }
        }

        var customBinding = new CustomBinding(webHttpBinding);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < customBinding.Elements.Count; counter++)
        {
            if (customBinding.Elements[counter] is WebMessageEncodingBindingElement)
            {
                WebMessageEncodingBindingElement webBE = (WebMessageEncodingBindingElement)customBinding.Elements[counter];
                customBinding.Elements[counter] = new GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement(webBE);
            }
            else if (customBinding.Elements[counter] is TransportBindingElement)
            {
                ((TransportBindingElement)customBinding.Elements[counter]).MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            }
        }

        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = webServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEngageWebServiceREST), customBinding, "");

        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior() { AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true, DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json });
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior());
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new HelpPageEndPointBehavior("Product Suite"));

        var serviceDebugBehaviorLocal = webServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        if (serviceDebugBehaviorLocal == null)
        {
            webServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior
            {
                IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            if (!serviceDebugBehaviorLocal.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults)
                serviceDebugBehaviorLocal.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

        }`

Await and appreciate ideas & thoughts to troubleshoot/resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Dileep

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refer to the following configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior" name="VM1.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="VM1.IService" behaviorConfiguration="rest" bindingConfiguration="mybinding" >
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="rest">
          <webHttp/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.